# Oracle Wallet Setup ORA-12578

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, wallet, oracle-se

I am having trouble setting up the Oracle Wallet on a new box connecting to a new database.  I have added the following lines to my SQLNET.ORA:

```
SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=c:\oracle\Wallet))
```

The wallet is created without error, the credentials added, and I can list the credentials back from the wallet without a problem, but when I go to use them I get an ORA-12578 as follows:

```
C:\oracle\Wallet>sqlplus /@MYDB

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Oct 31 16:57:53 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12578: TNS:wallet open failed
```

I am on a 64 bit box using the 32 bit 11.2 client to connect to an 64 bit 11.2 database.  Logging in without the wallet works fine.  The error message indicates that I should turn tracing on.  I have done so, but don't see anything obvious.  Does anyone have a suggestion before I contact Oracle support?

Comment: See this link
https://cn.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2179635 /Danny

Comment: I didn't see the problem based on your link, but it did give me a chance to tackle the problem again.  See my answer for the strikingly simple and obvious answer.

Comment: I had the same issue. After removing a space in the sqlnet.ora before the entry WALLET_LOCATION solved the problem for me. " WALLET_LOCATION" -> "WALLET_LOCATION"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out from the trace file that there was line in the sqlnet.ora file that it didn't like.  I narrowed it down to the WALLET_LOCATION line and finally recognized that there was a missing parenthesis at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use the below entry which is a working copy on my wallet store.

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY = c:\oracle\Wallet)
     )
   )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_VERSION = 0
```